# Sidebar implementation allows excessive vertical scroll

Tags: html, css

[This is a sidebar implementation for Bootstrap.](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/)

However if you open it in mobile or emulate it in Chrome. You can notice that you can scroll to the left as well as down to the point where it's beyond the page. Can't figure out what's causing it and how to fix it.

The basic question is how to disable the excess vertical scroll and bonus question is preventing horizontal scroll.

**Edit: Problem doesn't occur on iOS emulator. Seen in Chrome debug and Android phone.**

Comment: Tried it with the iOS simulator - only breaks inside the Chrome "debug tool" are you sure it isn't simply a bug inside this tool. I tried the answers below still the same problems.

Comment: It breaks on Android phones as well.

Comment: Strange behavior - can't find a div or similar which is beyond that point. - will try to find a solution.

Comment: Odd behavior indeed. I'm not able to use overflow: hidden anywhere properly.

Answer (score 1):

Tried it now with iOS Chrome, iOS Simulater, Safari - no problems with scrolling or overflow.

Now tried it with Chrome on Mac OS X with Debug tools set to a mobile Device (which one doesn't matter) And facing this issue: 
[image: Page above the right area]

I will come back with a possible fix for this or maybe an already added issue for Chrome on mobile/android. `overflow:hidden`, `overflow-y:hidden` and also a new div around the whole `wrapper` with `overflow:hidden` doesn't solve this issue.

**Update:**
Removing the `position:absolute` from `#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper` will remove that problem but causes the right content div to lose it's width. If you now add a new additional `min-width` the same problem for height calculation will occur. It looks somehow like a real Chrome Bug because it doesn't occur for me in Safari (mobile + Desktop) or Firefox (mobile + Desktop) only on Chrome for smaller screens.

Comment: It seems to be related to the padding on #wrapper.toggled if there's no padding, the scrolling doesn't occur.

Comment: Removing the padding for #wrapper.toggled prevents the odd behavior but the outcome is different in that the sidebar covers the content instead of pushing it to the side.

Comment: right. It could also be a problem related to the `position:absolute` of `#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper` and `position:absolute` from `#page-content-wrapper`. removing it without removing the other things. also another outcome. but we're on the right way.

Comment: if you change the `position:absolute` to `position:relative` for `#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper` the issue itself will be gone - but still if you then assign a `min-width` to it to achieve the same result - *same* problem will occure. - really strange

Comment: We are here facing an issue with the calculation of the height after the the transition with the `width:100%` block happened.

Comment: You should open an issue for the github example you showed us above: https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/issues maybe the developer has more idea's than we have. You can simply reference to this stackoverflow question/answer. I will also follow the issue there and update this answer asap we found a solution for it. Found an already opened issue which added the broken functionality: https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/issues/1

Comment: Added a comment to it - maybe we have some luck.

Answer (score 0):

What if you hide the overflow when the navigation is opened?

```
#wrapper.toggled {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Change the page-content-wrapper's position to relative

```
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work still scrolls. You can edit the CSS of that page and check as well.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the excess vertical scroll on the menu:

```
.sidebar-wrapper {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

To remove the horizontal scroll:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. You can edit the CSS of that page and check as well.

Comment: I did...and it worked for me...no vertical scrollbar for the menu and no horizontal scrollbar

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox in Responsive Design Mode

Comment: I've updated that it only shows up on Chrome debug and Android. Thanks for looking into it.